# Laravel sortBy() not working to sort a collection

Tags: laravel

I want to sort a collection by name column. Using sortBy() method is not working.

```
    $collection = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection($test);

    return $collection->sortBy('name');
```

Comment: Please, explain better in that way sortBy() doesn't work. Exception? Empty collection?

Comment: It returns a collection without sorting it. Like there is no sortBy().

Comment: Can you give an example of the data that you are trying to sort?

Comment: The name column is simple words, they are names.

Answer (score 21):

For me only worked example exactly as in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby)

```
$statisticCollection = collect($statistics);

$sorted = $statisticCollection->sortByDesc('date');

return $sorted->values()->all();
```

So the problem was that I did not save the sorted result to a variable before returning it.

Comment: I don't think the intermediate variable is the important part; you should be able to write `sortyByDesc('date')->values()->all()` and get the same result.

Answer (score 7):

I found that I had to use `values()` after sorting, as suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is:

```
$collection = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection($test);

return $collection->sortBy('name')->all();
```

Check how it is done in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby).

Comment: same result, unordered

Comment: Could you try `dd($collection);` and post the results in your question. So we can see what is returned,

Comment: The data I'm trying to sort is inside "data" key, because the result is paginated. I think that's the problem. But how can I sort that? sortBy('data.name') didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The default sortBy for Laravel is defined as ascending:

```
public function sortBy($callback, $options = SORT_REGULAR, $descending = false)
```

If you were looking to sort descending use `sortByDesc`:

```
public function sortByDesc($callback, $options = SORT_REGULAR)
{
    return $this->sortBy($callback, $options, true);
}
```

Where the first parameter `$callback` can be a `string` or a `callable`, so your code could look something like this with items sorted descending:

```
$collection = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection($test);

return $collection->sortByDesc('name')->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `\App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection()` doesn't have the method `sortBy()`. It's another type of collection (`AnonymousResourceCollection`).

As a workaround, you can convert it into the `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` like this:

```
$collection = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection($test);

$convertedCollection = collect($collection);

return $convertedCollection->sortBy('name')->toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

If the Laravel default sorting doesn't work for your purpose, try to do this:

```
$collection = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection->sortBy(function ($element, $key) {
  return yourFunctionForSorting($element['name']);
 });
```

Replace obviously "yourFunctionForSorting", with your sorting criteria.

Comment: could you give an example of yourFunctionForSorting please, to sort alphabetically?

Comment: @Josh Try to do this:
 substr($element['name'], 0, 1);

Comment: still not ordering

Comment: Retry with this:

$collection = \App\Http\Resources\MyResource::collection->groupBy(function ($element, $key) {
    return substr($element['name'], 0, 1);
});

Comment: @Josh if you retrieve the elements from a relational database, try to sort collection with an sql query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183831/discussion-between-tudor-and-josh).